# Do Diretide recipes expire?

Tags: dota-2

I just received two annoyingly specific recipes at the end of a game of Diretide.

Do I have to scramble and find what they want before Diretide goes away, or will they stay in my inventory forever, awaiting those items?

Comment: What is Diretide? A specific game-mode?

Comment: @Raven Dota 2's Halloween event.

Comment: @FAE Then yes, it probably doesn't merit its own tag.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It is also a specific gamemode.

Answer (score 4):

It's the new crafting system. Those recipes will stay. Usually items that get removed after a certain time (or at a certain point of time) are marked with an expiry date.